# I want to dismiss a page like Instagram when we swipe right in swiftUI

Tags: swiftui, dismiss

when I dissmiss the page, I have to stick my finger against the edge of the screen, I would like to be able to dissmiss anywhere on the screen like on Instagram

```
extension UINavigationController: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    override open func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = self
    }

    public func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return viewControllers.count > 1
    }
}
```

Comment: Anywhere on the screen? I think you mean the same direction i.e: horizontal but instead of having to move your finger to the edge you want to be able to do it from a closer distance right?

In that case I would say lookup ```.dragGesture``` and use that get the translation of the gesture from whichever edge you put your gesture in to programatically dismiss your view using that.